# Use multiple TimerServices with Websphere AS

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I want to use several `javax.ejb.TimerService`'s with different thread pools. How can I do it with WebSphere AS?

I founded how to create several `com.ibm.ws.scheduler.SchedulerImpl`, but it doesn't implement TimerService (so using directly `SchedulerImpl` is platform-dependent). I think I should wrap `SchedulerImpl` with `TimerService`, but I can't find way doing it.

Enviroment: WebSphere AS 8.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently supported.  All EJB timers use the same underlying scheduler.  If this capability is important to you, you could [open an RFE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181)